# My D Drive is Read Only

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, repair, reboot, read-only

After failing to import data from one Oracle database to another (in my D drive) my computer hung and I had to manually reboot my machine. Now my D drive is read only. I cannot create files, add files, or delete files in the D drive.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: Your `D:` drive is a probably in a *dirty* state as a result of the ungraceful shutdown. You can confirm that by starting a command prompt as administrator and running this command: `fsutil dirty query D:` If that's the case, perform a full disk check: `chkdsk D: /r` Then report back the output you got.

Comment: Yes, the D: drive is dirty but when i try to do a full check I get the response: Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process. Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first. ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N)

Do I go ahead with this or not?

Comment: If it's in use it's better not to force a dismount. Try restarting in Safe Mode and see whether you still get the same message. By the way, you do have a backup, right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying over necessary files from my D: drive to my C: drive and then reformatting my D: drive.